# d3 svg transition has slight unwanted horizontal movement on Firefox

Tags: html, d3.js, svg

The following has some SVG squares that march upwards once per second. In Google Chrome it looks fine. In Firefox, the squares shift right and left by about 1 pixel which is not what I intended.

Can anyone help figure out why?

I'm sorry this code snippet is not simpler; this is about as basic as I could go from a much longer file in which I removed all the unrelated aspects.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
    <style type='text/css'>
      .hidden { 
        display: none;
      }
       
      #ticktock {
        position: absolute;
        top: 550px;
        left: 400px;
      }
      svg rect.cell {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
      }
 
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(event) {
 
        var L = 25;
        var maxFacetCount = 8;
     var state = {
      nexttick: 0,
      ticksize: 500,
      n: -8,
      nx: 8,
      wheel: [],
            nfacet: maxFacetCount,
      init: true,
            ticktock: true
     };
    
       
     function update_state(state)
     {
        if (state.ticktock)
        {
          if (state.wheel.length >= state.nfacet)
            state.wheel.shift();
          state.wheel.push({n: ++state.n });
                 
           }
         
     }
  
      state.wheel = state.wheel.slice(-1);
 
     function prepare_view(state)
     {
      var width = 60 + (state.nx+0.5)*(L+2);
      var height = 5 + (state.nfacet+0.5)*L;
      var svg = d3.select("#wheel-container").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height);
        
             var x1 = L*0.5+5;
      var wheel = svg.append('g')
       .attr('id','wheel')
                .attr('transform','translate('+x1+',0)');
 
     }
     
     prepare_view(state);
      function facet_enter(facets, t)
     {
      var facet = facets.append('g');
 
            for (var i = 0; i < state.nx; ++i)
            {
                facet.append('rect')
                      .attr('x',i*L)
                      .attr('y',0)
                      .attr('width',L)
                      .attr('height',L)
                  .attr('class','cell');
            }
      facet_move(facet, state.init ? null : t);
     }
     
     function facet_move(facet, t)
     {   
      (t ? facet.transition(t) : facet)
           .attr('opacity',function(d,i) { 
            var age = state.n - d.n;
              return age == 0 ? 0 : 1-age/state.nfacet; })
         .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate(0,'+((d.n-state.n+state.nfacet-1)*L)+')'; });
     }
     
     function facet_update(facets, t)
     {
      facet_move(facets, t);
     }
      
     function update_view(state, ticktock)
     {
         
      var wheel = d3.select("#wheel");
      var facets = wheel.selectAll('g');

        if (state.ticktock)
        {
        var t = d3.transition().duration(300);
        var upd = facets
          .data(state.wheel, function(d,i) { return d.n; });
        
        upd .call(facet_update, t)
         .enter()
          
         .call(facet_enter, t)
 
        upd.exit()
         .transition(t)
                     .attr('transform','translate (0,'+(-L)+')')
            .remove();
 
       }
        else
        {
          // tock
          var t = d3.transition().duration(100);
          var t2 = t.transition().duration(100);

          var upd = facets
          .data(state.wheel, function(d,i) { return d.n; });
        
        upd.call(facet_update, t)
         .enter()
         .call(facet_enter, t);
 
        }
      }
     var tmr = d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
      var do_something = false;
      while (elapsed >= state.nexttick)
      {
       do_something = true;
       state.nexttick += state.ticksize;
      }
      if (do_something && !(d3.select('#pause').property('checked') ))
      {
          state.ticktock = !state.ticktock;
           
         update_state(state);
       update_view(state);
       state.init = false;
      }
     } );
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id='wheel-container' ></div>
    <form class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="pause" name="pause">pause</input>
    </form>
    <div id='ticktock' class='hidden'></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like floating-point rounding errors strike again. I changed to `shape-rendering: crispEdges;` and then rounded to an integer `translate` in one of the root elements and that seems to fix most of it (still a little residual y-axis shift).

was:

```
             var x1 = L*0.5+5;
            var wheel = svg.append('g')
                .attr('id','wheel')
                .attr('transform','translate('+x1+',0)');
```

changed to:

```
             var x1 = Math.round(L*0.5+5);
            var wheel = svg.append('g')
                .attr('id','wheel')
                .attr('transform','translate('+x1+',0)');
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
    <style type='text/css'>
      .hidden { 
        display: none;
      }
       
      #ticktock {
        position: absolute;
        top: 550px;
        left: 400px;
      }
      svg rect.cell {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }
 
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(event) {
 
        var L = 25;
        var maxFacetCount = 8;
     var state = {
      nexttick: 0,
      ticksize: 500,
      n: -8,
      nx: 8,
      wheel: [],
            nfacet: maxFacetCount,
      init: true,
            ticktock: true
     };
    
       
     function update_state(state)
     {
        if (state.ticktock)
        {
          if (state.wheel.length >= state.nfacet)
            state.wheel.shift();
          state.wheel.push({n: ++state.n });
                 
           }
         
     }
  
      state.wheel = state.wheel.slice(-1);
 
     function prepare_view(state)
     {
      var width = 60 + (state.nx+0.5)*(L+2);
      var height = 5 + (state.nfacet+0.5)*L;
      var svg = d3.select("#wheel-container").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height);
        
             var x1 = Math.round(L*0.5+5);
      var wheel = svg.append('g')
       .attr('id','wheel')
                .attr('transform','translate('+x1+',0)');
 
     }
     
     prepare_view(state);
      function facet_enter(facets, t)
     {
      var facet = facets.append('g');
 
            for (var i = 0; i < state.nx; ++i)
            {
                facet.append('rect')
                      .attr('x',i*L)
                      .attr('y',0)
                      .attr('width',L)
                      .attr('height',L)
                  .attr('class','cell');
            }
      facet_move(facet, state.init ? null : t);
     }
     
     function facet_move(facet, t)
     {   
      (t ? facet.transition(t) : facet)
           .attr('opacity',function(d,i) { 
            var age = state.n - d.n;
              return age == 0 ? 0 : 1-age/state.nfacet; })
         .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate(0,'+((d.n-state.n+state.nfacet-1)*L)+')'; });
     }
     
     function facet_update(facets, t)
     {
      facet_move(facets, t);
     }
      
     function update_view(state, ticktock)
     {
         
      var wheel = d3.select("#wheel");
      var facets = wheel.selectAll('g');

        if (state.ticktock)
        {
        var t = d3.transition().duration(300);
        var upd = facets
          .data(state.wheel, function(d,i) { return d.n; });
        
        upd .call(facet_update, t)
         .enter()
          
         .call(facet_enter, t)
 
        upd.exit()
         .transition(t)
                     .attr('transform','translate (0,'+(-L)+')')
            .remove();
 
       }
        else
        {
          // tock
          var t = d3.transition().duration(100);
          var t2 = t.transition().duration(100);

          var upd = facets
          .data(state.wheel, function(d,i) { return d.n; });
        
        upd.call(facet_update, t)
         .enter()
         .call(facet_enter, t);
 
        }
      }
     var tmr = d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
      var do_something = false;
      while (elapsed >= state.nexttick)
      {
       do_something = true;
       state.nexttick += state.ticksize;
      }
      if (do_something && !(d3.select('#pause').property('checked') ))
      {
          state.ticktock = !state.ticktock;
           
         update_state(state);
       update_view(state);
       state.init = false;
      }
     } );
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id='wheel-container' ></div>
    <form class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="pause" name="pause">pause</input>
    </form>
    <div id='ticktock' class='hidden'></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```